# ModelState invalida

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

eu tenho uma classe chamada, `Colaborador`. e o colaborador tem um banco.

```
 public class Colaborador
 {
  public virtual Banco Banco { get; set; }
  public Guid? BancoId { get; set; }
 }
```

o meu problema, é que mesmo o banco sendo opcional, da invalida a modelState, pois alguns campos da classe Banco, são obrigatórios.

eu tentei fazer assim:

```
if (colaboradorViewModel.Banco.NomeDoBanco == null)
            {
                colaboradorViewModel.Banco = null;
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Estado = new SelectList(_estadoAppService.ObterTodos(), "EstadoId", "Uf");
                ViewBag.Usuarios = new SelectList(_usuarioAppService.ObterTodos(), "UsuarioId", "Nome");
                return View(colaboradorViewModel);
            }
```

mesmo assim, ele continua validando os atributos do objeto `banco`.
como eu resolvo isso??

Meu ColaboradoConfi, está assim::

```
public class ColaboradorConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Colaborador>
    {
        public ColaboradorConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Colaboradores");
            HasKey(c => c.ColaboradorId);

            HasOptional(c => c.Banco).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.BancoId);

        }
    }
```

Banco Config:

```
   public class BancoConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Banco>
    {
        public BancoConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Bancos");
            HasKey(b => b.IdBanco);
            Property(b => b.NomeDoBanco).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            Property(b => b.Agencia).HasMaxLength(10).IsRequired();
            Property(b => b.Conta).HasMaxLength(10).IsRequired();
            Property(b => b.DigitoAgencia).IsOptional();
            Property(b => b.Digito).IsOptional();
            Property(b => b.Op).IsOptional();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como está o mapeamento do banco? Dê um Inspecionar no ModelState para vermos os erros e coloque também o print la na pergunta =)

Comment: vou editar a pergunta, e colocar a config

Comment: Como está o BancoConfig?

Comment: editei a pergunta e postei o bancoConfig

Comment: Cara, que estranho... Se inspecionar o ModelState ele te dá alguma mensagem?

Comment: não da erro, ela apenas da invalida!, não valida, pq a propriendade da classe banco, é obirgatória.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98738/discussion-between-andre-santarosa-and-rafael-passos).

Comment: cara, dá um select nos errors e manda pra gente +/- assim : var erros = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();

Comment: Como eu te falei, não da erro, apenas, da false, na modelState, pq os atibuto Nome, agência e conta da classe Banco são obrigatório.

Comment: Coloque todo metodo do controller e view